# ¿Se puede pasar el valor de una variable local, a otra funcion?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tengo una variable local en mi funcion `main`. ¿Se pueden pasar datos de esa variable a una funcion cualquiera? 
Por ejemplo, pasar de `main` a la funcion `x`, el valor de la variable `k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la 'funcion x' es llamada dentro de la funcion main() esto es posible.

```
Main()
    {
        variable k;       
        k= valor;

       FuncionX(k);
    }
```

de lo contrario necesitas que la variable 'k' sea global.

```
variable k; 
Main()
    {            
        k= valor;       
    }

FuncionX(variable)
    {            
        k= valor;       
        ...
    }
```